# Check if length of all vectors is the same in Rust

Tags: rust

Given a vector of vectors of some value `T`, ie. `Vec<Vec<T>>`.

What's the idiomatic way to check if the inner vectors have the same length? (without external dependencies)

That is, `true` if all the inner vectors have the same length, and `false` otherwise.

Comment: What behavior do you want for a vector of zero items?

Comment: @Shepmaster assuming there is always at least 1 vector present

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.all) method to check if all elements of an iterator match a predicate. Then just compare against the first element in the list.

```
fn main() {
    let vec_of_vecs = vec![
        vec![1, 2, 3],
        vec![1, 2, 3],
        vec![1, 2, 3],
        vec![1, 2, 3],
        vec![1, 2, 3],
        vec![1, 2, 3, 4], // remove this to prove that it works for both cases
    ];
    let all_same_length = vec_of_vecs
        .iter()
        .all(|ref v| v.len() == vec_of_vecs[0].len());

    if all_same_length {
        println!("They're all the same");
    } else {
        println!("They are not the same");
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, there's `all_equal` in itertools crate - map `Vec`s to their lengths, then run it. But it requires an external dependency.

Comment: Thanks @Michail, I am aware of it `itertools`. Let's assume no external deps (updated question)

Comment: This panics when `vec_of_vecs` is empty, though.

Answer (score 3):

An other solution more generic and idiomatic in my opinion:

```
fn all_eq_len<'a, T, E: 'a>(collection: T) -> bool
where
    T: IntoIterator<Item = &'a Vec<E>>,
{
    let mut iter = collection.into_iter();
    if let Some(first) = iter.next() {
        let len = first.len();
        iter.all(|v| v.len() == len)
    } else {
        true
    }
}
```

And of course using itertools:

```
use itertools::Itertools;

vec_of_vecs.iter().map(|v| v.len()).all_equal()
```